# While insmod .ko file facing below error message

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

In order to build the module  used below makefile

```
obj-m := hello.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

**system used redhat**

```
[  479.193629] hello: version magic '4.18.0-214.el8.ppc64le SMP mod_unload modversions relocatable ' should be '4.18.0-214.el8.ppc64le SMP mod_unload modversions mprofile-kernel relocatable '
[root@alp11 PatchTest]# '
```

Comment: It seems the `.ko` file you have is **incompatible** with your running kernel. Normally, every kernel module is built against the kernel, into which it is intended to be loaded. If you think that you have correctly built the module, then you need to describe how exactly you have built it. Normally, a question on Stack Overflow contains **more** than just a error message. Please, (re-)read [ask] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I think the kernel was built with a toolchain that supported the *mprofile-kernel* option, but the module was built with a toolchain that did not support that option.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev & lan-abbott,There are still issues with other modules